# Magento 2.4 - Add class for decimals in the price

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, price, magento2.4

I'm use Magento 2.4 and I need to change the format of the final price. I need to add a class for decimals. I want to add some css style to the decimals in the price. For example decimals must be much smaller than other numbers in the price.
How I can make my final price to be like this:

[image]

Thank you

**EDIT**

I'm found something maybe will help to find the solution much quick. How I can use this for example in the product list?

```
$first_amount = 29.95;
$my_array = explode(".", $first_amount);
echo $my_array[0];
echo $my_array[1];
```

also I found this solution, but the same I don't know how I can implement this for magento 2

```
$float        = 12.054;
$parts        = explode('.', (string)$float);
$whole_number = $parts[0];
$numerator    = trim($parts[1], '0');
$denominator  = pow(10, strlen(rtrim($parts[1], '0')));
```

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js is of use for you?

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you already know where to edit the price in PDP. So is simple CSS

```
<span class="price-test">
$60<small class="price-decimals">99
    <br>
    <small class="price-decimal-text">
        /each
    </small>
</small>
```

CSS:

```
small.price-decimals {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* line-height: 14px; */
}


span.price {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

span.price-test {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

small.price-decimal-text {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

[image: This is how it looks]